# Unable to change html table heade

Tags: jquery

With the following HTML I am trying to manipulate this with the subsequent JQuery code:

table class="tickets"
thead
tr
th class="priority" title="Priority"

```
$j(document).ready(function() {
if(location.pathname == '/organizations/30031077/requests' ) {
var header = "Project Type";

$j('.priority th').replaceWith(header);
}
});
```

Is there a problem with how I am referencing the 'priority' class and its th element? No errors and the tickets table header (Priority) does NOT get changed to 'Project Type'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the j :

```
$('th.priority').replaceWith(header);
```

Comment: Not necessarily. What if he has this defined at the top? `var $j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: Yep, here your are right. But this shortcut is not shown in the snippet

Comment: Thanks everyone, element order was critical and th.priority worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you put your `priority` class in the `th`, and use `text`.

Try:

```
$('th.priority').text(header);
```

Or:

```
$("tickets th").text(header);
```

The way you are trying it would only work if `th` was in an element that is descendent to the `priority` element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$j('th.priority').text(header);
```